# MATLAB: After deleting imrect object, can not create another

Tags: matlab, image-processing, callback, interactive

I'm having a problem when developing a simple program for manual image cropping. I used `imrect` to let the user drag and create rectangle selected area, and use `getPosition(imrect_object)` to get the position information for further cropping (using `imcrop`). I need a feature that I could 'undo' a rectangle selection, so I looked it up on the net and used `'KeyPressFcn'` callback. You can see the code in the end for more description. Also an example is at the end.

However, whenever I 'undo' an rectangle creation, I couldn't create another rectangle in the same figure. I got the error `'imageslib:iptPointer:invalidHandleMultipleInput'` but I can't find enough information to solve it by myself.

Thanks very much for your help. Any advice is invaluable to me!

Code is here:
The first one is the main program. It used another callback function in another file (shown later).

```
close all
clear all
clc
global posR;
global Rec;
reference = 'w1DIC'; %specifier of reference file
target = {'w2405','w3488','w4561'}; %specifier of target file
targetBkgClear = 1; %if=1 then cropped target files would be subtracted by    background noise which is calculated using borders of the target files.

%--------------READ FILE--------------
%select the dir where the image data are saved
    pathdir=uigetdir(pwd,'Select image data dir');
    filename1AllStruct=dir(fullfile(pathdir,'*.TIF'));
    pathname1=[pathdir '\']; %THIS LINE IS PLATFORM SPECIFIC (WINDOWS)!
    filename1={};
    cropRegions={};
    for i=1:length(filename1AllStruct)
        currFileName = filename1AllStruct(i).name;
        if strfind(currFileName,reference)
            filename1{length(filename1)+1}=currFileName;
        end
    end

m=length(filename1);
%-------------PROCESS EVERY FILE, GET CROPPING AREAS-------------
for i=1:m
    I = imread(strcat(pathname1,filename1{i}));
    I = imadjust(I);
    posR = {};
    imshow(I);
    set(gcf,'KeyPressFcn',@keyboard_response); %set keyboard callbacks
    while true
         try
            Rec=imrect;
            posR{length(posR)+1}=getPosition(Rec);
         catch ME
            disp(ME.identifier);
            break
         end
    end
    cropRegions{length(cropRegions)+1} = posR;
    close all
end
%-------------PROCESS EVERY FILE, USE IMCROP TO CROP AND WRITE RESULTS-------------
for i=1:m
    tG = {};
    for j=1:length(target)
        tG{length(tG)+1} = strrep(filename1{i},reference,target{j});
    end
    for j=1:length(target)
        try
            I = imread(strcat(pathname1,tG{j}));
        catch
            error(sprintf('Target file not found %s',tG{j}));
        end

        if targetBkgClear==1
            bkg = [I(:,1) I(:,end) I(1,:)' I(end,:)'];
            bkg = mean(bkg(:));
            I = I-bkg;
        end

        for k=1:length(cropRegions{i})
            Ji = imcrop(I,cropRegions{i}{k});
            outName = strrep(tG{j},target{j},strcat(target{j},sprintf('_%d',k)));
            outName = strcat('Crop_',outName);
            imwrite(Ji,outName,'TIF');
        end
    end
end
```

The callback function is here:

```
function keyboard_response(fig_obj,event)
global posR;
global Rec;
switch event.Key
    case 'C'
        imcontrast
    case 'c'
        imcontrast
    case 'u'

        size(posR)
        Rec

        Rec.delete(); %delete most recent rectangle
        temp={};
        for i=1:length(posR)-1
            temp{length(temp)+1} = posR{i};
        end
        posR = temp;%rewrite rectangle position records

        size(posR)
        Rec

    case 'U'
        Rec.delete(); %delete most recent rectangle
        temp={};
        for i=1:length(posR)-1
            temp{length(temp)+1} = posR{i};
        end
        posR = temp;%rewrite rectangle position records
end
end
```

Here is an example:

The testing directory has following files:
[Testing directory content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh1j7.jpg)

Then I ran the main program and select the testing directory.

Then I create two rectangles in the poped figure window:
[Two rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94mAw.jpg)

Then I press 'u' to 'undo' the last operation and then the second rectangle was deleted.

Then I try to create a new rectangle in the same figure by dragging the mouse. Right after mouse button's up, the figure window closed and I catched the error message `'imageslib:iptPointer:invalidHandleMultipleInput'`.

Sorry that I can't provide more links because I'm only allowed to provide two. I'm using MATLAB R2016a.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your KeyPress breaks out of the rectangle selection without letting it finish. I assume that leaves unfinished things. It's probably easier to assign a key, `spacebar` for example, to let the user select another rectangle. Also `temp{length(temp)+1}` can probably be replaced with `temp{end+1}`

Comment: Hi Gelliant, I have recoded it all, and it worked. So it seems that it is the unfinished `imrect` command resulted in the error. Thanks very much for your help!